# How can node.js process trigger a callback function when it exit?

Tags: node.js, process

That is my code, I tried two ways to trigger a callback function when process exit.

My purpose is when process exit, it can write some word to a txt file.

The way I exit process is click the 'close' button on the `node.exe` window,the other way is key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

But both of these methods are not effective.

```
process.on('exit', function() {
  chatCache.each(function(i,self,length){
    util.writeJSONtoTxt(chatChache_filePath,JSON.stringify(self));
});
});
//--------------------------------------------
var stdin = process.openStdin();

process.on('SIGINT', function () {
 console.log('Got SIGINT.  Press Control-D to exit.');
 chatCache.each(function(i,self,length){
    util.writeJSONtoTxt(chatChache_filePath,JSON.stringify(self));
});
});
```

Comment: ..My english is so poor...

Comment: @Rakkun ,how to use synchronous call ? Thx!

Answer (score 2):

You have to kill the process from `SIGINT` handler like this :

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
 console.log('Got SIGINT.  Going to exit.');
 //Your code to execute before process kill.
 process.kill(process.pid);
});
```

Then it will exit when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> .

`process.on('exit', function() {});` is only executed when your node.js code completes executing (finishes event loop) without any errors, which will never happen if you run a server.